# How to assign .POST return value to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How to assign `.post` return data to variable.actually I am trying to update high-chart.
high-chat data in array.

**JavaScript**

```
$.post( "system/return_pages/counter.txt", function(data) {//return value data});
```

Above `.post` mathod give me return value this is my number of visitor value.I should need this value in high-chat.But the real scenario i have tried to make global variable and assign it.But when i put in high-chart array than there no show any value.I am showing down high-chart code and with what I have done.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    var date = new Date();
    var d  = date.getDate();
    var day = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var month = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
    var yy = date.getYear();
    var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;
    var count = "";
    $.post( "system/return_pages/counter.txt", function( value ) { count =data; //count value 35});

    var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#32353A']
    });
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            margin: [ 50, 30, 80, 60]
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Visits this month'
        },
        xAxis: {

            categories: [
            date
            ],
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                align: 'right',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '9px',
                    fontFamily: 'Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Visits'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    'Visits: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
            }
        },
            series: [{
            name: 'Visits',
            data: [count],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                rotation: 0,
                color: '#F07E01',
                align: 'right',
                x: -3,
                y: 20,
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.y;
                },
                style: {
                    fontSize: '11px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }, 
            pointWidth: 20
        }]
    });
});


});
```

The result of high chart null I mean count variable null every time I am new on JavaScript.I don't know what problem in my code.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

That's because AJAX is **asynchronous** - by the time that variable get's assigned the rest of the code has already ran, enter *callbacks*. You can pass a function to run once your AJAX request has finished, this function should contain all of the logic to be done.

```
$.post( "system/return_pages/counter.txt", function( value ) {
    //value is only accessible in here
    //Either do your logic in here, or pass "value" to another function
});
```

In short, put all your high charts logic into the callback of your AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

The `.post` method is asynchronous (the `a` in `ajax`). The return value of $.post is the [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) and has nothing from the database in the subsequent code.

On a related note, you may have a bug. I think

```
$.post( "system/return_pages/counter.txt", function( value ) { count =data; //count value 35});
```

should instead be

```
$.post( "system/return_pages/counter.txt", function( data) { count =data; //count value 35});
```

Comment: thanks for replay this is just return value I mean you can use any costume variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have trhee options, (one bad and two good ones):

- (bad) set AJAX to be synchronous
- (good) create chart **inside** callback:

  ```
  $.post( "system/return_pages/counter.txt", function( value ) { 
      count = data; //count value 35 
      chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  });
  ```
- (good) create empty chart (first!), and in callback update that chart:

  ```
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  $.post( "system/return_pages/counter.txt", function( value ) { 
      count = data; //count value 35 
      chart.series[0].setData([count]);
  });
  ```